# CodenameOne: Flickering in vertical tabs

Tags: codenameone

I encountered an unresolved UI interference between containers and tabs when the tabsposition is to Left or Right.

white color covers some tabs after selecting a tab.

** I don't use any gradient colors.

** i didn t override any paint or use any revalidate.

As you can see the tabs are on the left behind the white blanck.

[image]

Comment: Screenshots and/or code sample is required to help you in resolving this.

Comment: Hi, i just added a snapshot. this happen when i select a tab. i tried to disable animations. but same thing. and i worked with gui builder.

Comment: Is that only on the device or does that happen on the simulator as well? Did you style the tabs in any specific way?

Comment: same thing on the device. samsung galaxy tab 10.1. i just set tabs background to an image. padding top =1, bottom=1, & i set border line

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this on the device and this worked for me. So I'm guessing this might be related to the border line or some other theme element that you might have. If not I suggest isolating the difference between the test case and your app:

```
Form hi = new Form("Tabs", new BorderLayout());
Tabs tb = new Tabs();
tb.setTabPlacement(Tabs.LEFT);
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, tb);
tb.addTab("Tab 1", new Label("Tab 1"));
tb.addTab("Tab 2", new Label("Tab 2"));
tb.addTab("Tab 3", new Label("Tab 3"));
tb.addTab("Tab 4", new Label("Tab 4"));
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: i m sorry this still happens everytime i use webBrowsers. i use gui. same config as yours above. the webBrowser container is on top of tabs. and i notice that there is a container named "null" on top of web browser which i can 't delete or edit. this container "null" is created automatically when creating a webBrowser.

Comment: That might be the actual problem. Since the web browser is a peer component its probably the reason for this behavior: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/understanding-peer-native-components-why-codename-one-is-so-portable.html if you change my test case to add a `BrowserComponent` to the second tab does it reproduce the issue?

Comment: yes. i did have same issue twice with webBrowsers but when i change them to other components no problem ! i even had this issue with horizontal tabs using a box layout Y when scrolling down.

Comment: OK, I see this even in the simulator now. A small tweak to the example shows this. Filed an issue here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1711